# Simplify the expression and eliminate any negative exponents

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Simplify the expression and eliminate any negative exponent(s). Assume that all letters denote positive numbers.

$$\sqrt[4]{\frac{162x^3y^5}{2x^7y}}$$

I attempted it many times and got multiple answers which were all wrong... I'll post the one that I think is closest:

MY WORK:

\begin{align*}
\sqrt[4]{\frac{162x^3y^5}{2x^7y}} & = \sqrt[4]{\frac{81 \cdot 2 \cdot x^3 \cdot y^4 \cdot y}{2 \cdot x^4 \cdot x^3 \cdot y}}\\
& = 3xy \sqrt[4]{\frac{\require{cancel}\cancel{2} \cdot \cancel{x^3} \cdot \cancel{y}}{\cancel{2} \cdot \cancel{x^3} \cancel{y}}}\\
& = 3xy
\end{align*}

Please help, the homework is due in under 48 hours and we get 5 tries to submit each answer. I already got this wrong 4 times so I have one final try before the question locks and marks it as wrong.

Comment: Please see this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.  You can see how I typeset your work by right clicking on a formula, then selecting Show Math As TeX Commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: we can simplify to $$\sqrt[4]{\frac{81y^4}{x^4}}=\frac{3|y|}{|x|}$$

Comment: Oh, so the x goes on the bottom... I considered that but I wasn't sure. Thank you.